# Eclipse IDE Learning Curve

Tags: visual-studio, eclipse

I am a C# guy with pretty good grasp of Visual Studio IDE usage (using it since VS2003).
Right now, I am doing a proof of concept app using Eclipse 3.4.1.

Is there any good reference or book which describes the usage of Eclipse IDE, compared to Visual Studio. Is there any Eclipse guide for Visual Studio users :)

Thanks, in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For example:

- http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/os-eclipse-visualstudio/index.html
- http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/edu/os-dw-os-eclipsevs-i.html